# What is the meaning of "sum product" as mentioned in Numpy documentation?

Tags: numpy

In the NumPy v1.15 Reference Guide, the [documentation for numpy.dot](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) uses the concept of "sum product".

Namely, we read the following:

> - If a is an N-D array and b is a 1-D array, it is a sum product over the last axis of a and b.
> - If a is an N-D array and b is an M-D array (where M>=2), it is a sum product over the last axis of a and the second-to-last axis of b:
>     `dot(a, b)[i,j,k,m] = sum(a[i,j,:] * b[k,:,m])`

What is the definition for this "sum product" concept?
(Couldn't find such a definition on Wikipedia, for example.)

Comment: Sum of the products of the corresponding elements. `np.dot([3,4,4], [4,3,2])` is the same as `(3 * 4) + (4 * 3) + (4 * 2)`.

Comment: Btw. I don't think "sum product" is a technical term, sounds more like they made that word up as they went along.

Comment: It's short for `sum of the products`, which is widely used.

Comment: @hpaulj sounds more like product of sums. (Trust me on that---I'm German, I know a thing or two about compound nouns)

Comment: Having the same understanding than @Paul Panzer, I find the "sum product" term confusing and would rather call this a "product sum", hence my perplexity.

Comment: @PaulPanzer ` @JérômeL I also agree with your parsing of "sum product". My Guess is that it was influenced by Excel's `SUMPRODUCT` (which is thus similarly confusing), but if it was not, that at least indicates that the term has some currency.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication

```
That is, the entry c[i,j] of the product is obtained by multiplying 
term-by-term the entries of the ith row of A and the jth column of B, 
and summing these m products. In other words, c[i,j] is the dot product 
of the ith row of A and the jth column of B.
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product

```
Algebraically, the dot product is the sum of the products of the 
corresponding entries of the two sequences of numbers.
```

In early math classes did you learn to take the matrix product, by running one finger across the rows of `A` and down the columns of `B`, mulitplying pairs of numbers and summing them?  That motion is part of my intuition of how that product is taken.

---

For the 1d second argument case, `np.dot` and `np.matmul` produce the same thing, but describe the action differently:

- If `a` is an N-D array and `b` is a 1-D array, it is a sum product over
  the last axis of `a` and `b`.
- If the second argument is 1-D, it is promoted to a matrix by
  appending a 1 to its dimensions. After matrix multiplication
  the appended 1 is removed.

  In [103]: np.dot([[1,2],[3,4]], [1,2])
  Out[103]: array([ 5, 11])
  In [104]: np.matmul([[1,2],[3,4]], [1,2])
  Out[104]: array([ 5, 11])

Appending the dimension to `B`, does:

```
In [105]: np.matmul([[1,2],[3,4]], [[1],[2]])
Out[105]: 
array([[ 5],
       [11]])
```

This last is a (2,2) with (2,1) => (2,1)

Sometimes it is clearer to express the action in `einsum` terms:

```
In [107]: np.einsum('ij,j->i', [[1,2],[3,4]], [1,2])
Out[107]: array([ 5, 11])
```

`j`, the last axis of both arrays is the one that gets 'summed'.

Comment: I agree, the case of Matrix product is indeed familiar. In contrast, I don't get the intuition of the theory behind a matrix * vector product as in `np.dot([[1, 2], [3, 4]], [1, 2])` yielding `array([ 5, 11])`, especially from a shape/dimension perspective.

Comment: This is in effect doing `np.array(( np.dot([1,2], [1,2]), np.dot([3,4], [1,2]))`, that is 2 vector dot products, one for each row of `A`.  `np.array(( 1+4, 3+8))`.

Answer (score 0):

For Numpy, "sum product" means "matrix multiplication". Not to confuse with SUMPRODUCT and MMULT functions in Excel, which have different meanings.